# How can I display the content of a map in PrimeFaces

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a hashMap: `HashMap<Entity1,List<Entity2>>();`. How can I display content of these map with using `p:dataTable` in PrimeFaces ? I tried this where sheet is map

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tabulky.tabulka.sheet}"
             var="item"
             scrollable="true"
             height="500"
             emptyMessage=" Ziadne data nenajdene &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Listocky"/>
    </f:facet>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <c:forEach items="#{(item.value)}" var="item1">
            <p:column headerText="Hokej">
                <h:outputText value="#{item1.atr1}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item1.atr2}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="&nbsp;:&nbsp;}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item1.atr3}" /> 
            </p:column>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{tabulky.tabulka.sheet}"
             var="item"
             scrollable="true"
             height="500"
             emptyMessage=" Ziadne data nenajdene &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Listocky"/>
    </f:facet>
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <p:dataTable value="#{(item.value)}" var="item1">
            <p:column headerText="Hokej">
                <h:outputText value="#{item1.atr1}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item1.atr2}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="&nbsp;:&nbsp;}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{item1.atr3}" /> 
            </p:column>
       </p:dataTable>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Use the `p:dataTable` replace the `c:forEach`

Comment: thx but I convert these map to list and create new class entry but thx anyway maybe I try this solution too